# Is it possible to not accept a badge?

Tags: support, badges

I'm close to meeting a certain goal that will award me a gold badge. Meeting such goal is out of my control (think of badges awarded when getting a certain number of upvotes or saves).

I'd prefer not getting the badge. **Is there any way to prevent getting it?**

Comment: Just curious.  What is an example of a badge that some people would prefer not to get?

Comment: @GEdgar: Just take a look at the edit history of this question.

Comment: Related question on Meta SE (from over 12 years ago): [Can I get my gold badge revoked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65271)

Answer (score 7):

No, it is not possible to not accept a badge. <s>As far as I am aware, there is no functionality that would prevent you from getting the badge.</s>* As I mentioned in the comments, maybe just move on. It is not such a big deal, really. Although badges are nice and give you a sense of achievement, it is hardly the case other users really care about what badges you have in your virtual pocket.

*: an individual user can ask the community moderators [to dissociate a post from their account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa/96746#96746). It is not clear to me if this situation is a proper use of this functionality, so we can wait for a community moderator to chime in.

Comment: I seem to recall that an individual user can ask the community moderators [to dissociate a post from their account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa/96746#96746).  In the circumstance that seems to underlie the OP's concern, I think this would do what is needed.

Comment: @hardmath I am not sure if this is really a good reason to do that (I actually wasn't aware of this functionality), since the OP's justification is "this question I asked ages ago is vague and not well thought out." I am sure a very large portion of the user base here feels the same way about at least one (if not several) of their posts after having moved forward in their academic careers, and hence I would discourage setting a precedent here.

Comment: @hardmath You say you *seem to* recall, but by the looks of it you actually do you recall: you have included a link confirming that. ;)

Comment: Moderators don't have the ability to disassociate posts, @hardmath - only staff can do that. While we will occasionally do what you're saying - as the link you shared explains - we generally expect there to be some amount of explanation and we will often only do it as a one-time request. While I can't speak to the specific case here, as it would be up to that team to determine, the link you have is generally the policy.